# Entity Framework Package Migration Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to migrate an entity for my MVC application.  I am totally new at this and know very little about .NET MVC.  The issue I am having is that when I run the migration I get the error "Keyword not supported: 'userid'".  I don't know what 'userid' he is referring to.  Can someone point to me how the migration works so that I can perhaps find out what 'userid' it is referring to in the error?

Thank you very much!

> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName BBGDB Checking if the context
>   targets an existing database... System.ArgumentException: Keyword not
>   supported: 'userid'.    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings
>   appConfigConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
>   name, AppConfig config)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Keyword not supported: 'userid'.

Comment: By the way, I don't have a 'userid' column in my tables, but I do have 'UserId'.  But even when I dropped the existing table it still shows the same error. Where is it referencing?  Can someone help me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it refers to the userid in your default connection string. Inspect your connection string and replace userid with user id.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much that solved it.  Now I'm wondering my connection string had 'userid' instead of 'user id'.  Must be my mind getting sleepy from learning about .NET MVC.  Thanks Wiktor Zychla!